# ubuntu 14.04 unity desktop without panel and launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, panel, opengl

Now after having succeeded to make running the new Ubuntu 14.04 I see, that Unity seems not to work (the desktop appears without launcher and panel). Gnome is working.
CCSM is possible to open under Gnome but not under Unity. If I change to console (Ctrl-Alt-F1) and try to start unity then OpenGL seems to be the problem.
So how to start OpenGl and Unity plugin, if this is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Answered in question  by OP:

> Update: NOW I GOT IT! Maybe for the fundi (Kiswahili for "specialist") it was no question but for me it was something to find out:
>   CCSM was only possible to start under Gnome. But there was a conflict between some Gnome-features and Unity-plugin or openGl. Finally it was possible to resolve those conflicts step be step and now the launcher as well as the top panel are there.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? It is driving me crazy... no one else seems to have resolved it, there are many similar threads but I am in the same state ccsm will not start.

Comment: Don't know... something to do with ccsm...