# Ubuntu Session not starting Unity

Tags: unity, launcher

I've been fiddling around with different desktop environments lately. I started with Gnome Fallback, then Gnome 3 then XFCE and now I decided to use Unity.

I installed `ubuntu-desktop` and launched "Ubuntu" in Lightdm but no panel or launcher appears. To make them appear I need to do CTRL+ALT+F1, login and execute:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
setsid unity
```

It then appears after I execute that but every time I login I need to do that. In addition, there are no indicators in the top right corner.

Does anyone know how I can make the indicators appear and make the launcher and panel appear when I log in?

Thanks,

Comment: 'Prt sc' doesn't work?

Comment: @NoTime - Is PrtSc supposed to take a screenshot and save it to `~/Pictures`? Cause it's not doing that.

Comment: Printscreen normally saves it to clipboard, unless you have changed normal keybinds

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought it would have put them in `~/Pictures` as that's what GNOME3 and XFCE does by default. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Have you tried [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Comment: Also [ubuntu 14.04 unity desktop without panel and launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452671/ubuntu-14-04-unity-desktop-without-panel-and-launcher)

Comment: @bain - Firstly, thanks for your comments.
My question is different from the possible duplicate you said as none of the answers actualy specify what to do to make it so that I don't need to enter the code every time I login.

Comment: `setsid unity` is the command to start unity from the command line. It is not the solution to your problem. Did you try resetting your Unity configuration, or any of the other suggested answers?

Comment: Can you create a new user account and try logging in to that?

Comment: @bain - I just tried resetting my unity configuration and the same as before happened; no side launcher or panel.

Comment: @bain - I'll try that.

Comment: @bain - Yeah, when I created a new user everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Try `rm -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1`

Comment: @bain - Nup, it still doesnt work. :-/

Comment: See the answer to [How to reset main user account?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43584/how-to-reset-main-user-account)